# Can't `mount -o loop` an ISO from an NFS share (RHEL)

Tags: linux, mount, iso-image

I have a large NFS share with a variety of software ISOs on it.

I've only tried this on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, but when trying to do the following, the `mount` comes back with an error indicating no permissions to mount. Why would this be happening?

NFS is mounted thusly:

```
mediaserver:path/to/isos /media/nfs
```

This is the `mount` call that fails

```
mount -o loop /media/nfs/product.iso /tmp/product
```

If I copy the ISO, there is no issue. The NFS share is mounted rw.

How can I loop mount the ISO from the NFS share without copying it first?

Comment: `no_root_squash` allows `rw` mounts for me (nfsv4).

Comment: @fread2281 - so you followed the steps in [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/186890/978)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can mount an ISO as read-write.

Try mounting the iso with `-o loop,ro,noexec`.

You can also modify the NFS `/etc/exports` as to add `no_root_squash`, which should allow `rw` mounts.

Comment: How come the bounty for this hasn't been awarded?

Comment: @imoatama - my *guess* is that it will auto-award at the end of the bounty period... but I don't know for sure

Comment: *To the moderator:* This is an old question that was given a 50 rep bounty a few months after it was posted. The answer was accepted 6 days ago, but somehow I ended up only today with only 25 rep. Could this glitch be corrected?

Comment: Accept and Bounty are not holding hands any more. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56789/9314 - If the bounty isn't manually awarded, only half is given at the end by the auto-bountifier.

Comment: @random: I know, but it was manually awarded the very first day of the bounty, which is probably why the SU site ignored the award.

Comment: sorry about the half-bounty being awarded :( ..I *did* accept your answer, and would've expected the whole bounty to go to you

Comment: @warren: Not your fault. The FAQ states accepting is only from the 2nd day. But it should either have stopped you from accepting, or awarded the full bounty. What happened is that you lost 50 reps, I got 25, and 25 simply evaporated.

Comment: hmmm. Well, next time I shall have to wait an award the bounty later in the process

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of presenting all alternatives for any future viewers the following works also:

```
mount -o loop -t iso9660 /media/nfs/product.iso /tmp/product
```

I've found it easier to remember to simply specify the filesystem, in this case ISO using the -t option.